# Payum-bundle STRIPE checkout, prefill e-mail adress

Tags: symfony, stripe-payments, payum

I´m using

`payum/payum-bundle V.2.2.1` with  `payum/core V.1.4.3` and `payum/stripe  V.1.4.3`

So far the billing process is working fine using `stripe_checkout`

but I dont get it to work to prefill the users e-mail-adress which I already know. The Stripe docs mention the way to go [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#optional)

But I have no idea how to do that in prepare with payum-bundle.

My prepareAction looks some like this:

```
$gatewayName = 'stripe';
$storage = $this->get('payum')->getStorage('foo\CoreBundle\Entity\PackagePayment');
$payment = $storage->create();


$payment->setNumber( uniqid() );
$payment->setPackageId($package->getId());
$payment->setCurrencyCode('EUR');
$payment->setTotalAmount($amount); 
$payment->setDescription($package->getType() );
$payment->setClientId($package->getIdentity() );
$payment->setClientEmail($package->getPaymentemail());
$details=array();
$payment->setDetails($details);
$storage->update($payment);


$captureToken = $this->get('payum')->getTokenFactory()->createCaptureToken(
    $gatewayName, 
    $payment, 
    'foo_core_done_stripe'
);

return $this->redirect($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
```

And Stripe Checkout gets the right values for description, amount and currency, but the email-field is not prefilled even though I set the ClientEmail of Payment

So how can I pass the Email?

Comment: Try to add to details, the better way is to fix convert action https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/src/Payum/Stripe/Action/ConvertPaymentAction.php#L28

Comment: thank you, you pointed me to the answer :-) the action is fine as i´m able to add details in my controller, the problem was the view, i overrided it in config.yml and added the data-attributes to the script tag